# How to use Softphone(Open CTI) in a Custom Visualforce page with out enabling sidebar?

Tags: opencti

I am trying integrate a Softphone layout and make a call using "sendCTIMessage" with appropriate parameters including phone number, So far the call is being made if the softphone layout is loaded in the sidebar, But our requirement is to load the softphone layout in custom location inside custom visualforce page and we are not able to succeed.
Is it possible to load softphone layout in an iframe inside custom visualforce page and make the calls happen.